# Predict Circle to Circle intersection in Time

Tags: c#, math, vector, geometry, collision-detection

I need to find if two round objects will collide and if yes when in time they will.

My approach is this:

```
if (Vector3.DistanceSquared(a.Position, b.Position) < Math.Pow(a.Radius + b.Radius,2))
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                float result;
                for (int t = 1; t < 150; t++)
                {
                    result = Vector3.DistanceSquared(a.Position + t * a.LinearVelocity, b.Position + t * b.LinearVelocity);
                    if (float.IsInfinity(result))
                    {
                        return float.PositiveInfinity;
                    }
                    if (result <= Math.Pow(a.Radius+b.Radius,2))
                    {
                        return t;
                    }
                }
                
                return float.PositiveInfinity;
            }
```

I am clearly missing something, or I am totally wrong cause the results are not as expected.

I also think performance wise the loop might be wrong but I am not sure how could I avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we write squared distance between circle centers:

```
(x2-x1+t*(vx2-vx1))^2+(y2-y1+t*(vy2-vy1))^2=(r1+r2)^2
let dx = x2-x1, dy = y2-y1, dvx = vx2-vx1, dvy = vy2-vy1, rr = r1+r2
(dx+t*dvx)^2+(dy+t*dvy)^2=rr^2
dx^2+2*dx*t*dvx+t^2*dvx^2+dy^2+2*dy*t*dvy+t^2*dvy^2-rr^2=0
t^2*(dvx^2+dvy^2) + t*(2*dx*dvx+2*dy*dvy) + (dx^2+dy^2-rr^2)=0
t^2*a +             t*b +                   c               =0
```

This is quadratic equation for unknown t

```
D = b^2 - 4*a*c
if D<0 there are no collisions
if D=0 there is one touching in moment t = -b/(2*a)
else there are two solutions
t1 = (-b - sqrt(D)) / (2*a)
t2 = (-b + sqrt(D)) / (2*a)
```

One or both times might be negative - means collision "was in the past"

Smaller time is moment of collision, larger time - moment of "leaving", I think it is not needed here

Comment: Alright this makes sense. How do you define variables a,b,c?

Comment: `a = (dvx^2+dvy^2) ` and so on (I especially aligned columns)  -  coefficients for t powers

Comment: Thank you for your very much! You actually helped me clear my mind, the reason it was failing was because the simulation was in 3D space even if it was represented in 2D and I wasn't evaluating the Z!